# Tridion component linking in RTF field is not working properly

Tags: 2011-sp1, rtf

I have linked components in my RTF field. I have published the pages containing the both components. Now in the site when I click on the link for the first time, I get error as below:

> Error Loading the Page
> The page you are looking for has moved,
>   been replaced, or is currently unavailable to view.

The link opens fine when I click on it the second time.
Now if I close the browser and open the link again for the first I get the same error.
Can anybody tell me what could be the reason.
I am using Tridion 2011SP1

Comment: Can you share, how the link is rendered after publishing?

Comment: And it does look like a server-side error. Anything in relevant logs?

Comment: Are you sure that deployment of everything is complete?

Comment: @Saurabh, Link is rendered as <a href="/relativeURL.jsp" class="compLink" title="Test new" target="_blank"><strong>LinkComponent</strong></a>

Comment: @Nuno, I cant find anything in logs related to this.

Comment: Yes @DominicCronin the site has been running for a while now so everything is in place.

Comment: So as per your comment, you are rendering static link (not a dynamic tridion link). If I got you correct, the issue is on the application side not with Tridion.

Comment: Well, it could still be a dynamic Tridion link if that's in the source of the rendered HTML for a visitor (and the markup in the published page's source has a `tcdl` tag). It does seem like a server or application issue, though.

Comment: How have you running your Tridion content delivery? For some reason, your application may be treating the component links just like a static file and not processing it for dynamic linking. Can you make sure that all your modules run for all requests?